# Wrap element then append another element inside it

Tags: jquery

Look at this code

```
<div class="preview">
    <img src="link" alt="" class="overlay" />
</div>
```

what i need to do is to wrap the  inside div call "overlay" then append another div called "overlay2" to be like below

```
<div class="preview">
    <div class="overlay">
        <img src="link" alt="" class="overlay" />
        <div class="overlay2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i'm tried to use .wrap and append but i didn't know how to use this with one command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very simple

```
$('.preview').append('<div class="overlay2"></div>')
$('.overlay').wrap('<div class="overlay"></div>')
```

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/32JSW/

Comment: Second line should be `$('.overlay').wrap('<div class="overlay"/>');` - shoudn't include the "overlay" text

Comment: you're kidding, right? because if you click my jsfiddle, you will also see that i've colored all divs, and the OP didnt ask for that. should i delete my answer for trying to be didatic?

Comment: No, your original answer (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/d3c15d5d-9a34-4702-b476-beee47d4dd3d/view-source) included the text "overlay" which didn't match the expected output in the question. You apparently agree since it looks good now :)

Answer (score 8):

You may try this

```
$('div.preview img')
.wrap('<div class="overlay"></div>')
.after('<div class="overlay2"></div>');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pA3PQ/) (See the source).

### OR

```
$('div.preview img')
.wrap($('<div/>', {'class':'overlay'}))
.after($('<div/>', {'class':'overlay2'}));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pA3PQ/1/) (See the source).

### Output

```
<div class="preview">
    <div class="overlay">
        <img src="link" alt="" class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgElement = $('div.preview').find('.overlay');  
$('div.preview').remove('img.overlay');    
$('div.preview').append("<div class='overlay'></div>");    
$('div.overlay').append(imgElement);  
$('img.overlay').after("<div class='overlay2'></div>");
```

Comment: Need to escape your single quotes for `'overlay'` in the `append()` calls.

Comment: just read about the wrap function. That is a better approach than the one I have mentioned. http://api.jquery.com/wrap/