# jQuery wrap Strange behavior

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I wrote a code that wrapped two existing elements into a new one. My first attempt looked like this:

```
var $btn = $("button"),
    $ul = $btn.next("ul"),
    $div = $("<div></div>");

$btn.wrap($div);
$div.append($ul);
```

And I was surprised to see that after the code ran, the `ul` was gone from the DOM. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paska/8jdvjp45/1/).

I was able to fix it selecting the `div` from the DOM between `wrap` and `append` like this ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paska/8jdvjp45/2/)):

```
$div = $btn.parent();
```

Event after a few searches in Google I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12906983/310276) and replaced the 3 lines in my code with this ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paska/8jdvjp45/3/)):

```
$btn.wrap($div).after($ul);
```

However I'd like to understand what is going on with the `div` and `wrap` method. Why does the `ul` disappear in the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrap command creates a copy of the given element, so the created 'div' is not the same as the 'div' stored in your variable.
From the docs:

> A copy of this structure will be wrapped around each of the elements in the set of matched elements. This method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

more at: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

If you want to see your div, put this code `$('body').append($div);` after your code and you will see that your 'ul' did not disappear. You put the 'ul' element inside your 'div' element but you are not using your 'div' anywhere.

Comment: I didn't know that `wrap` used a clone instead of the original element. That explains it. I assumed it was like `append` which uses the original element and "If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target except for the last one." http://api.jquery.com/append/